# Section Heading Centering problem

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

```
\begin{center}
    \section*{\textcolor{blue}{Ukaaranta }}
    \end{center}
    \subsection*{Shabhu Harivat}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{shambhu harivat} 
\begin{center}
    \section*{\textcolor{blue}{Krostru Shabda}}
\end{center}
```

I have a need to create something like this, however when I run this program, it gives error at the second `\end{center}`.

Funny but the same command works above. I did not do anything different, just copy pasted and changed the text.
Similar commands elsewhere in the document work just fine. I have no clue why it's behaving like this.

Hit ? and R - enter and it gives the desired output but it's a pain to do that every time.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you want to centre your titles and make them blue, then redefine the title format using a package like `titlesec`.  If all your sections and subsections are going to be unnumbered, redefine them that way, also with `titlesec`.  If you don't want numbers in your table of contents, set the `secnumdepth` to 0.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\color{blue}\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
    \section{Ukaaranta}
    \subsection{Shabhu Harivat}
    \section{Krostru Shabda}
\end{document}
```

(You can adjust the vertical spacing of the titles also with `titlesec` using the `\titlespacing` command.)

[image: example output]

Answer (score 43):

`\begin{center} ... \end{center}` creates a list with centered items. It should not be used for headings.

`\centering` works here, because you use `\section*` which doesn't process the argument for TOC or page headers. Your code could be changed to:

```
\section*{\centering\textcolor{blue}{Ukaaranta }}
\subsection*{Shabhu Harivat}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{shambhu harivat} 
\section*{\centering\textcolor{blue}{Krostru Shabda}}
```

For a consistent document you should create macros for the style, such as

```
\newcommand*{\sectioncolor}{blue}
\newcommand*{\sectionformat}{\centering\color{\sectioncolor}}
...
\section*{\sectionformat Ukaaranta}
```

This way you could change the style of the whole document at just one place.

For more possibilities have a look at the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package which provides many features for customizing style and spacing of headings.

Comment: Instead of "\section*{\centering\textcolor{blue}{Ukaaranta }}", can we use

Answer (score 11):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}
```

([Source](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29618))