# Undefined control sequence and \chapter error

Tags: sectioning

I’m getting an “undefined control sequence” error with the following code, using TeXstudio:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\chapter{CHAPTER 6}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Articles don't have chapters, so the `article` class doesn't have a `\chapter` command. Maybe you want to use the `report` or `book` class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 49):

The `article` class doesn't define the `\chapter` command, because articles don’t have chapters. Instead they have sections, subsections, etc. If you really want to use `article`, then you might want to consider using `\section`, `\subsection` and so on.

If you really want to use the `\chapter` command, then I’d suggest using the `book` or `report` document classes.

Separately, you generally shouldn’t use `\begin{center} … \end{center}` for headings. It’s really better used to make lists or similar. A better way to centre your title headings is to use the `titlesec` package, which is described in [another question on TeX.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8546/section-heading-centering-problem).

Comment: Wow this saved my day!

Comment: In my case, \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}  

Still it shows “undefined control sequence” error in \chapter{Introduction}

Answer (score 14):

Command `\chapter` is undefined in `article`. It is defined in `book` or `report`.