# Facing Problem in Chapter name and section numbering

Tags: sectioning, chapters, overleaf

[image]
I am writing my FYP report and in this report, I need to add chapters but I am facing this error marks as "cross", the Chapter number is not showing in the document as well as section numbering is not correct as logically all sections must have numbering according to their respective chapter.
Help me with this.
Thanks

```
{
    \chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\section{Objective}
\section{Methodology}
\section{Organization of Report}
\chapter{Literature Review} \\
\chapter{Requirement Specification}
\section{Product Requirement}
\section{Organizational Requirement}
\section{External Requirement}
\chapter{Project Design}
\section{Methodology}
\section{Architecture Review}
\subsection{Stator}
\subsection{Rotor}
\subsection{Switching Circuit}
\subsection{Electric Vehicle}
\section{Design Description}
\subsection{Stator}
\subsection{Rotor}
\subsection{Switching Circuit}
\subsection{Electric Vehicle}
\chapter{Implementation}
\section{Development Stages}
\subsection{Hardware}
\subsection{Simulations}
\chapter{Evaluation}
\section{Results}
\subsection{Theoretically}
\subsection{MATLAB-Graphically}
\chapter{Conclusion and Future Work}
\section{Conclusions}
\section{Future Work}
}
```

Comment: The article class doesn't have chapters. Use report instead.

Comment: Sorry Bernad i don't get you

Comment: can you further help me

Comment: I just mean you should use `\documentclass{report}`, not `article`.

Comment: Thank u soo much I get this one.

Comment: You're welcome! If you have any difficulties for the layout, feel free to ask.

Comment: The code you show will result in an error message such as "Undefined control sequence \chapter". Once you get an error message, do not look at the output, since TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file after an error, it does not try to make sensible output. Before looking at the output, fix the errors first. Overleaf is quite good at hiding the error messages from the users, so look if there is a [white number on a red rectangular background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY6n0.png) right next to the "recompile" button and click on the red rectangle to see the errors.

Comment: A search for the aformentioned error message reveals for example this related question [Undefined control sequence and \chapter error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117151/134144) to which your question is basically a duplicate.