# Title of Section in Center (thesis writing)

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

For writing thesis, I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside, 12pt]{book}
```

In it, sectioning was coming at left. I want them in center.

This has been considered before (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8546/section-heading-centering-problem)).

But, I tried from its answer, the following.

```
\section*{\centering\textcolor{blue}{Ukaaranta }}
```

I was getting error.

Also, instead of this, can I delete `\textcolor{blue}`? Since I color them in black only.

Is it necessary to put * here?

---

The error was showing this:

> [PDFLaTeX] Finished with exit code 1
>
> Argument of \@sect has an extra } ...ion{\centering\textcolor{blue}{Ukaaranta }}
>
> Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete...ion{\centering\textcolor{blue}{Ukaaranta }}

Comment: What's the error message? And why is this tagged `texniccenter`? Of course you can delete `\textcolor{blue}` then

Comment: I am not so familiar with tags here. You may edit it with  appropriate tag.

Comment: You need the `*` for the unnumbered section (title), otherwise use `\section{\protect\centering...}`

Comment: Have you seen my answer at all: That will prevent the error!

Comment: By the way: You have some questions with answers but accepted none of them, this is not how TeX.SX works ;-)

Comment: yes. I am doing it, and it is working with some modifications. (I added this error, because of your first comment.)

Comment: yaa. I will "accpet" answers, sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
```

This will center all section, subsection, and subsubsection headers. If you want to center only section-level headers, change the second command to

```
\sectionfont{\centering}
```

Comment: Mico: Great. This works well, with less commands. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This works out of the box (remove `\usepackage{showframe}` later on!)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\section{\protect\centering\textcolor{blue}{Ukaaranta}}

\section*{\centering\textcolor{blue}{Ukaaranta}}

\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on Hupfer's solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\section[#1]%
{\hfill{#1}\hfill\quad\phantom{\thesection}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mysection{Ukarranta}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: centered text, left section number]