# Section title centering

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec

I am writing my PhD thesis in LaTeX. When I tried to center the section titles, awkwardly, it compiles without table of contents but whenever I write `\tableofcontents` an error occurs.

For centering, I wrote down

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8546/section-heading-centering-problem
 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278653/title-of-section-in-center-thesis-writing?lq=1

Comment: Use the `block` style, not `hang`.

Comment: for me this works fine.

Comment: @Bernard: Posting an answer perhaps? The question is vague, however ...

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I'll do it in a moment. Might be useful to show the difference between `hang`, `block` and `display` styles.

Comment: @Bernard Still interested in answering? :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B: I had completely forgotten. Thanks for reminding me. Done!

Answer (score 2):

`Titlesec` defines several shapes for section titles. Among which:

- `[hang]` is LaTeX default shape for section: label and section title aligned, staring from the left margin;
- `[block]` puts label and section title in a paragraph. Useful for centred section titles or with picture inclusion, for instance;
- `[display]` outs the label in a paragraph of its own, like the default \chapter;
- `[framed]`: like display, but framed.

For the alignment of titles, titlesec defines commands such as `\filcenter`, `\filleft`or `\filright`, to be used preferably to `\centering`, `\raggedright` or `\raggedleft` (there are small differences as to spacing).

So here, you can write

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

As nice classical variant,(for my taste…) is this:

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\scshape\filcenter}{\§\,\thesection}{1em}{}
```