# Centering top-level headings and left-aligning bottom-level headings in article class

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, apa-style

I have a document of type `article`. I am trying to create an APA style and I need all of my top-level headings in center (by top-level headings I mean all the `\section` headings) and all other bottom-level heading left-aligned. Here is my current settings:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{setspace,caption}
\captionsetup{font=doublespacing}% Double-spaced float captions
\doublespacing% Double-spaced document text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\lhead{RUNNING HEAD}

\title{my title}
\author{my name}
```

I was wondering how I can do that. I am aware of using `\section*{\hfil Introduction\hfil}`, however, apparently it does not work for `article` document.

Comment: There's an APA6 document class that might be helpful. Or see [Section header centering problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8546/2693).

Comment: "Top-level headings" = `\section`. What do you mean by "bottom-level headings"?

Comment: @Werner by bottom-level I mean any kind of `\subsection` or `\subsubsection`

Comment: @AlanMunn That is what I was looking for! Thx!