# How to make a paragraph indent and make the title centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have this code and this result. But I need the "Введение" to be in the middle and the line "Каждый из нас" to have a similar indentation as the "Целью реферата". how can this be done?

```
\section*{Введение}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Введение}

Каждый из нас ежедневно решает задачи различной сложности: как быстрее добраться в школу или на работу в условиях нехватки времени; в каком порядке выполнить дела, намеченные на текущий день, и т.д. Некоторые задачи настолько сложны, что требуют длительных размышлений для нахождения решения, другие задачи мы решаем автоматически, так как выполняем их ежедневно на протяжении многих лет. Но в любом случае решение каждой задачи можно подразделить на простые этапы.

Целью реферата является раскрытие базовых знаний об элементах  теории алгоритмов.

Для решения поставленной цели необходимо выполнить следующие задачи:
```

[image]

Ty for answer. I used this but I lost the numbering of the section and subsection. How do I get the numbering back?

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
```

guys please tell me how do I return the numbering of y section id subsection and that the list of references is displayed in the content

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) To center the section titles, you could use the `titlesec` package as for example shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8547/134144  Regarding the second half of the question: Using the `indentfirst` package might hep. For some more alternative approaches, see also: [No indent in the first paragraph in a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39227/134144)

Comment: Ty for answer. I used this but I lost the numbering of the section and subsection. How do I get the numbering back?

Comment: @leandriis  Hello. Сan you tell me what i need to add to make the numbering appear again?

Comment: For numbering of section and subsection you should not use stared version of those commands. Just `\section{...}` and `\subsection{...}`. In this case `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Введение}` is redudant.

Comment: @Zarko. If i use just section and subsection, then they are on the left and i need to move them to the center.

Comment: Regarding your recent update: How is this related to the list of references? Please clarify. Also, please spacify how subsection titles should look like. Do you also want them centered?

Comment: I doubt in this. Positioning of `\section{...}` and `\section*{}` should be the same. SInce we don't know anything about your document preamble we can only guess. Please provide an example of small document which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @leandriis. About the list of references. I need it to be displayed in the content.

Comment: Without knowing how you create your list of references, it is impossible to tell you how you can include it in the table of contents, I assume, this is what you refer to with "displayed in the contents". Since this is also not related to the horizontal alignment of section headers, I suggest, you "[ask a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" specifially on that topic. Please also prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and include it in your question.It is a lot easier to help if you provide a complete, small example document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its current state, your question is quite unclear. However, the following might get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\filcenter} %remove to get left aligned subsection headers

\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text. Do not use in actual document
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{section}

\lipsum[4]

\lipsum[4]

\subsection{subsection title}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed.